# tqdm: update total without resetting time elapsed

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm using tqdm as I recurse over a directory tree.  I don't know the number of paths I'll be using, and I don't want to build that list before I do the work just to get an accurate total count, I'd rather have it just update the progress bar as it goes along.

I've found that I can use 'reset(total=new_total)' just fine, but that also resets the time.  Is there a way I can keep the time but just set the total to something new?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the definition of `reset` function definition inside `tqdm` package:

```
    def reset(self, total=None):
        """
        Resets to 0 iterations for repeated use.

        Consider combining with `leave=True`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        total  : int, optional. Total to use for the new bar.
        """
        self.last_print_n = self.n = 0
        self.last_print_t = self.start_t = self._time()
        if total is not None:
            self.total = total
        self.refresh()
```

What you need is not to update values of `self.last_print_t`, and  `self.start_t` and just update the `total`

Instead of calling `t.reset(total=new_total)`, you should do the following:

```
t.total = new_total
t.refresh()
```

Comment: Great; that worked.  Now if I can only find out how to replace the default block character with a period... :)  Thanks!

Comment: It does fix the elapsed time, however future ESTIMATED time is stuck at zero for me after that.

Comment: works, but in a notebook the progressbar is not updated.

Comment: @karelv I've added an answer that updates the progressbar in notebook

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vishal's answer.
For notebook support the only way is to reset the progressbar:

```py
total += 1  # external total tracker
processed = pbar.n  # Get current progress to re-apply
pbar.reset(total)  # Reset and update total
pbar.update(processed)  # Re-apply progress
pbar.refresh()  # Redraw the progressbar
```

Runnable example:

```py
import queue
import time
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class ProgressQueue(queue.Queue):

    def __init__(self, maxsize: int = 0):
        super().__init__(maxsize=maxsize)
        self.pbar = tqdm(total=1, dynamic_ncols=True)
        self.total = 0  # Keep our own total tracker so we can update the Progressbar

    def task_done(self):
        super().task_done()
        self.pbar.update()

    def _put(self, item):
        super()._put(item)
        self.total += 1
        processed = self.pbar.n  # Get current progress to re-apply
        self.pbar.reset(self.total)  # Reset and update total
        self.pbar.update(processed)  # Re-apply progress
        self.pbar.refresh()  # Redraw the progressbar

    def join(self):
        super().join()
        self.pbar.close()


def produce(q: queue.Queue):
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            q.put(i)
            time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Producer error: {e}')


def consume(q: queue.Queue):
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            q.get(i)
            q.task_done()
            time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Consumer error: {e}')


q = ProgressQueue()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as tp:
    tp.submit(produce, q)
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the queue to have some items. Otherwise the queue can complete pre-maturely
    tp.submit(consume, q)

q.join()
```